# How to know if my app comes back to background‏

Tags: android

I started developing an app that requires the user to go through login every time.

Mainly I would like to know when the user clicks on my app icon and start it, so I would be able to start the login activity instead of the activity he left open in the last time he used the app.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that question has other implications that arise questions like, why would you want to do so? going again a consistent interaction for the user and along with the way the system works.

Obviating all that and as far as I'm concerned the only way to do so is to take the user to the login screen in all the onResume of all your activities with startActity.

Answer (score 0):

According to android documentation, you can acheive that via manifest.xml file.
by setting [android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) for your activity node in your manifest.

say your activity name is MainActivity then your manifest.xml should look like this:

```
.....
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver). From this you can know when your application is going in background and when your application come to foreground, no matter in which activity you are. Because it is observing application life cycle. So when app come to foreground then you need to start your LoginActivity so it will be on top of your application and user must have to login as like Banking application.

For LifecycleObserver, you need to register in onCreate() method of Application class of your app using below line of code.

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(appLifecycleObserver)
```

Create class for AppLifecycleObserver for above object (appLifecycleObserver)

```
class AppLifecycleObserver(val context: Context) : LifecycleObserver {
  /**
   * Call when your app come to foreground
   */
  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
  internal fun onEnterForeground() {
    //goto login activity

  }
  /**
   * Call when your app go to background
   */
  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
  internal fun onEnterBackground() {
  }

}
```

Dependency gradle required:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can now it by overriding onpause method on the activity and save the state user has left last time in the shared preference

you can see more about activity lifecycle here -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

and here is the activity lifecycle map

[image]

I hope my answer helps you but if you have another question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment :)